# Check for duplicate rows for a subset of columns in a Pandas DataFrameGroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a groupby object (grouped on Col1) like below:

```
Col1     Col2     Col3     Col4     Col5
----------------------------------------
AAA       001      456      846      239     row1
          002      374      238      904     row2
          003      456      846      239     row3

BBB       001      923      222      398     row1
          002      923      222      398     row2
          003      755      656      949     row3

CCC       001      324      454      565     row1
          002      744      345      336     row2
          003      567      355      756     row3
```

Is there a way to check for duplicate rows based on [Col3, Col4, Col5] within each group. In the example above, for group AAA, row 1 and row 3 match since Col3, Col4, Col5 values are same. Again in group BBB, row 1 and row 2 match. In group CCC, using above logic, we don't have any duplicate rows.

Can we create a list with 'n' boolean elements (where 'n' represents the number of groups), fill it with True if there is any duplicate for that group, else False. Therefore, for above example output would be:

`[True, True, False]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `groupby` column `Col1` then use `duplicated()` to check if there are any duplicated from `Col3` to `Col5`

```py
out = (df.groupby('Col1')
       .apply(lambda g: g[['Col3','Col4','Col5']].duplicated().any())
       .tolist())
```

```
print(out)

[True, True, False]
```

Comment: Thanks @Ynjxsjmh ! A followup question, how would the solution change if for example now duplicate within each group means return True if all rows match within a group (not just few), for example say for group AAA row1, row2, row3 all match (for Col3, Col4, Col5) so we return True, using same logic now group BBB should return False (since all rows dont match), group CCC also returns False. So output should be [True, False, False]

Comment: @inferno Maybe change `any()` to `all()`

Comment: Yes! I was playing around the answer and changed `any()` to `all()`. We also need to add parameter in duplicated as `duplicated(keep=False)` this will ensure that even the first element is marked as True (in case every row within a group matches).